# How to do normal IF-THEN in CoffeeScript (instead of DO-IF)

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

Here is how the condition is implemented in CoffeeScript (CS):

```
number   = 42
opposite = true
number = -42 if opposite
```

Which is equivalent to JavaScript:

```
number = 42;
opposite = true;
if (opposite) number = -42;
```

This is... cool, but kinda weird, this would be nice as an option, but I would conservatively use old good "if then" mnemonic, is that possible in CS?

Comment: http://coffeescript.org/#conditionals

Comment: oops, I did not notice the home page is _that_ long. thought it ends with `Usage`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [CoffeeScript's documentation](http://coffeescript.org/#conditionals) :

```
if happy and knowsIt
  clapsHands()
  chaChaCha()
else
  showIt()
```

Answer (score 0):

Of, if you are aiming for one-liners (which you should not):

```
number = if opposite then -42 else 42
```

Which translates to the ternary operator

```
var number;
number = opposite ? -42 : 42;
```